# I need to find duplicate rows in an array with specific conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, grid

### i have list of accounts and need to find the duplicate rows with specific conditions and show errors when there is more then one row with those condition.

1. same number and descriptions
2. same number different description
3. number is null and description same.
4. Different number and same description #    `

   ```
   const accounts = [
           { id: 1, number: '1', description: 'desc1' },
           { id: 2, number: '2',  description: 'desc2' },
           { id: 3, number: null, description: null },
           { id: 4, number: '1', description: 'desc1' },
           { id: 5, number: '1', description: 'desc3' },
           { id: 6, number: '1', description: 'desc4' },
           { id: 7, number: null, description: 'desc5' },
           { id: 8, number: null, description: 'desc5' }
         ];
       findDuplicates(accounts) {
         const duplicates = accounts
           .map((account) => {
             return {
               count: 1,
               number: account.number,
               description: account.description
             };
           })
         .reduce((arr, row) => {
           // try to find the current row in count array
           const existingRow = arr.find((countRow) => {
             return (countRow.number === row.number && countRow.description === row.description);
           });
           if (existingRow !== undefined) {
             existingRow.count += 1;
           } else { // otherwise, push it onto the count array
             arr.push(row);
           }`enter code here`
           return arr;
         }, []).filter((duplicateRows) => {
           return duplicateRows.count > 1; // filter the list down to only accounts with more than 1 account
         });
         return duplicates;
   ```

Comment: can you edit your question and share the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This one simple generator function trick can get you duplicates

```js
const accounts = [
        { id: 1, number: '1', description: 'desc1' },
        { id: 2, number: '2',  description: 'desc2' },
        { id: 3, number: null, description: null },
        { id: 4, number: '1', description: 'desc1' },
        { id: 5, number: '1', description: 'desc3' },
        { id: 6, number: '1', description: 'desc4' },
        { id: 7, number: null, description: 'desc5' },
        { id: 8, number: null, description: 'desc5' }
      ];

function *findDuplicates(accounts) {
  let bucket = [];
  
  for(let account of accounts) {
    const item = bucket.find(pr => pr.number === account.number 
      && pr.description === account.description);
    const item1 = bucket.find(pr => pr.number === account.number && pr.description !== account.description);
    const item2 = bucket.find(pr => pr.number !== account.number && pr.description === account.description);
    
    if(item1) {
      console.log(`${account.id}: same number ${account.number} different description ${item1.description} ${account.description}`)
      yield account;
      continue;
    }
    
    if(item2) {
      console.log(`${account.id}: different number and same description ${account.description}`)
      yield account;
      continue;
    }
    
    if(item) {
      console.log(`${account.id}: same number ${account.number} and same description ${account.description}`)
    yield account;
      continue;
    }
    
    bucket = [...bucket, account];
    
  }
}

console.log([...findDuplicates(accounts)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that did not work.  i need different combinations of duplicates.

Comment: Updated anwer. I included additional cases

Comment: Thanks. The output is what i was looking for. I am not much familiar with the generators.  is it possible to use the .reduce and filter to get those rows?

Comment: with `reduce` you'd have to put the content of for loop inside `accounts.reduce((bucket, value) => {<content> return bucket}, [])`

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I will try that now.